# Select statement in a variable

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have the following for loop

```
for i in (
select * from employees)

loop
--code
end loop;
```

Is it possible to assign the select statement in a variable like

```
sql_stat := 'select * from employees';
```

and in loop

```
for i in (
    sql_stat)
loop
```

When I tried the above I am getting error
*"Encountered the symbol loop"*

What is the correct way of doing this if I want to assign the select statement in a variable.

Thanks

Comment: I would try For i in ( exec(sql_stat)) or the equivalent syntax (I forget specific Oracle one ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ref cursors` to get result you want. Here is an example.

```
declare
      type t_cursor is ref cursor;
      c_cursor t_cursor;
      l_sql varchar2(123);
      l_var number;
   begin
     l_sql := 'select count(*) from T1';  -- your query goes here
     open c_cursor for l_sql;
     loop
       fetch c_cursor 
        into l_var;-- variable(s) of appropriate datatype you want to fetch data into
       exit When c_cursor%notfound;
       -- any work for processing fetched data goes here
     end loop;  
  end;
```

Comment: So that means I cannot use a variable in `for i in(<variable>)`? Thanks

Comment: you can if the variable is a cursor not a select appeared as a string

Comment: Can I use sys_refcursor instead of ref cursor? Any advantage over ref cursor? Thanks

Comment: They are the same. sys_refcursor variables (cursors) can be used to pass cursors from and to a stored procedure. Any variable of ref cursor type can be used for that too but they have to be declared in an in-scope package specification

Comment: Thanks Nicholas for your valuable answer and comments.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to store the select statement in a variable? One would only do this if part of the query is variable. For example the table_name.

Usually the query is static and the normal way of accessing the results of a query row for row is to use a cursor for loop such as this:

```
declare
   cursor c is 
     select column1,column2 
     from table;
begin
  for r in c loop
     dbms_output.put_line(r.column1||' '||r.column2);
  end loop;
end;
```